# Can't get permalinks working!

Tags: permalinks, mod-rewrite

I can't get WordPress pretty permalinks to work on my Fedora LAMP server.  If I set them and click a page/post link I'll get a ""Oops! This link appears to be broken."

- The .htaccess file is writable and being updated,
- mod_rewrite module seems to be loaded in my httpd.conf (See below)
- The errors in my apache log say simply "Document not found".

I'm at the end of my rope!  Here's the **httpd.conf**:

```
### Section 1: Global Environment

# start the rewrite engine (I ADDED THIS)
RewriteEngine on 

ServerTokens OS

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

PidFile run/httpd.pid

Timeout 120

KeepAlive Off

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 15

<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>


<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         2
MaxClients         150
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75 
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, in addition to the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses (0.0.0.0)
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so

#
# The following modules are not loaded by default:
#
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
#LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so

Include conf.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

### Section 2: 'Main' server configuration


ServerAdmin root@localhost

UseCanonicalName Off

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">


    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks


    AllowOverride None


    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>


<IfModule mod_userdir.c>

    UserDir disabled

</IfModule>


DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var

#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
#   MIMEMagicFile /usr/share/magic.mime
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog logs/error_log

CustomLog logs/access_log combined

ServerSignature On

Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"

<Directory "/var/www/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    # Location of the WebDAV lock database.
    DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>


IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable Charset=UTF-8

ReadmeName README.html
HeaderName HEADER.html

IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

AddHandler type-map var

AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml


Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
<IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/var/www/error">
        AllowOverride None
        Options IncludesNoExec
        AddOutputFilter Includes html
        AddHandler type-map var
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        LanguagePriority en es de fr
        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>


</IfModule>
</IfModule>


#
# Proxy Server directives. Uncomment the following lines to
# enable the proxy server:
#
#<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
#ProxyRequests On
#
#<Proxy *>
#    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
#    Allow from .example.com
#</Proxy>

#
# Enable/disable the handling of HTTP/1.1 "Via:" headers.
# ("Full" adds the server version; "Block" removes all outgoing Via: headers)
# Set to one of: Off | On | Full | Block
#
#ProxyVia On


NameVirtualHost *:80


<VirtualHost *:80>
 # start the rewrite engine
 RewriteEngine on
 ServerName www.example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/com_example_www
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of your config you have the following:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

You should change it to the following:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

The `AllowOverride` directive is what allows the `.htaccess` file to be read. If you still have trouble, make sure you change this in the

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
```

block as well (depending on where your site is located).

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Gavin- Bingo- you the man!